# Dual Instance Running / 2 Game.exe at a time

Tags: c++, winapi

I'm asking a little help. About CreateMutex in my Game.exe, I want to have a dual instance running or two (2) same Game.exe running but not more than that. As of now this is my code

```
const char szUniqueNamedMutex[] = "Game.exe";
HANDLE hHandle = CreateMutex( NULL, TRUE, szUniqueNamedMutex );
}
if( ERROR_ALREADY_EXISTS == GetLastError() )
{
MessageBox ( NULL,"Game is already executed, Multiple Execution is 
prohibited!", "Game.exe", MB_OK );
return FALSE; // Exit program
}
```

The current code can only run one instance or Game.exe

TIA. I hope someone can help me here.

Comment: Use a counting semaphore starting at 2 instead of the mutex.

Comment: do you have any reference for that? Thank you!

Comment: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms682438(v=vs.85).aspx

Comment: The answer should come naturally, once you start thinking about a "mutex" as the special case of a "binary semaphore".

Comment: Okay, this is too much confusing. I need to study more :(

Answer (score 1):

Using a mutex in the manner you are only allows 1 instance of your app to run at a time, regardless of the mutex's ownership.

To allow a finite number of app instances to run (in your case, 0 < X <= 2), use a [semaphore](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms685129.aspx) instead:

> The semaphore object is useful in controlling a shared resource that can support a limited number of users. It acts as a gate that limits the number of threads sharing the resource to a specified maximum number. For example, an application might place a limit on the number of windows that it creates. It uses a semaphore with a maximum count equal to the window limit, decrementing the count whenever a window is created and incrementing it whenever a window is closed. The application specifies the semaphore object in call to one of the wait functions before each window is created. When the count is zero—indicating that the window limit has been reached—the wait function blocks execution of the window-creation code.

For example:

```
const char *szUniqueNamedSemaphore = "Game.exe";
HANDLE hHandle = CreateSemaphore(NULL, 2, 2, szUniqueNamedSemaphore); 
if (!hHandle) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Unexpected error creating Execution semaphore!", "Game.exe", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}
if (WaitForSingleObject(hHandle, 0) != WAIT_OBJECT_0) {
    MessageBox(NULL, "Game is already running 2 times, additional Execution is prohibited!", "Game.exe", MB_OK);
    return FALSE;
}

... run the game logic ... 

ReleaseSemaphore(hHandle, 1, NULL);
```

A successful wait on a semaphore decrements its counter. A call to `ReleaseSemaphore()` increments the counter. The state of the semaphore is signaled when its counter is > 0, and unsignaled when it is 0